# Inserting XML data into existing XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to insert new XML data into an existing XML format based on certian conditions.  I have a query for the conditions, but the examples I've found to insert seems to throw the error "exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here is my XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myDataInfo
xmlns:fp="http://www.Myexample.com">
<myDataReport>
    <startTime second="16" minute="51" hour="8" day="1" month="9" year="2016"/>
    <myDataHub type="history" location="abc">
        <myDataSet location="def">
            <myData type="contact" id="9c1181ca-ffe7-46ae-9d37-fdefc05e59a0" batt="100" temp="24" name="Data2">
                <evt val="open" time="86160"/>
                <evt val="closed" time="86156"/>
            </myData>
            <myData type="motion" id="39ccc3d2-ab42-4f86-aa08-7f0eb665fece" batt="100" temp="24.3" name="Data3">
                <evt val="active" time="86384"/>
                <evt val="inactive" time="86380"/>
            </myData>
        </myDataSet>
    </myDataHub>
</myDataReport>
```

---

And my query to get:-

```
var eventResults1 = root.Descendants()
    .Elements(ns + "myData")
    .Where(el => (string)el.Attribute("name") == "def")
    .Elements(ns + "evt")
    .Select(el => new
    {
       t1 = el.Attribute("time").Value,
       v1 = el.Attribute("val").Value
    })
```

---

The data I want to insert into mydata "Data2"

```
<evt val="closed" time="87000"></evt>
```

I tried to use

```
Elements(new XElement("evt", "time=90000,val=active"))
```

But i'm not having any success in inserting.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to get the `myData` element that matches your criteria:

```
var myData = root.Descendants(ns + "myData")
    .Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Data2");
```

And then add a new child element:

```
myData.Add(new XElement("evt",
        new XAttribute("val", "closed"),
        new XAttribute("time", "87000")
    )
);
```

I'd suggest [reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693190.aspx) or some tutorials, as most of this stuff is in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it more difficult than it actually is.
Just know that `Elements("...")` will return only direct child elements (only one level down), and `Descendants("...")` will return every child element, no matter how deeply nested. So you don't need to use `Elements()` here, only `Descendants()`.

```
var myDataElement =
    // Find all elements with the name "MyData"
    root.Descendants("myData")
    //Filter out the one that has the attribute you're looking for
    .Single(element => element.Attribute("name").Value == "Data2");

//Add the new element
myDataElement.Add(
    new XElement("evt",
        new XAttribute("val", "closed"),
        new XAttribute("time", "87000")
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement addElement = doc.Descendants("myData").Where(x => x.Elements("evt").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("val") == "open").Count() == 0).FirstOrDefault();
            if (addElement != null)
            {
                addElement.Add( new XElement("evt", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("val","closed"),
                    new XAttribute("time","87000")
                }));
            }

        }
    }
}
```